# Magento: I'm having trouble getting an observer to fire after trying to hook to the aschroder_smtppro_before_send event; any ideas?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I've been working a bit now on a little project to implement a simple blacklist for *Magento CE 1.9.x* and *Aschroder's* **SMTPPro** email extension.  I've been in a couple of different directions with this, at first thinking that I was going to have to override `getTemplateSubject()`, and potentially some other methods, in order to intercept an outgoing email, as I don't believe that (sans-**SMTPPro**) Magento has any events that fire on dispatching of an email.  As a sidenote, corrections on any misconceptions that I may be having in this posting are very much appreciated.

So I've gone ahead and focused on tying in to **SMTPPro**'s `aschroder_smtppro_before_send` event to try to fire my code.  I want to eventually check the recipient address, look for a substring, and can any emails matching that criteria (potentially with a message to an admin) at some point in the future.  Right now, however, I can't even get the code to give me a `var_dump` just to know that it's even firing.  I did try tying the code to a different event, at one point (namely `controller_action_predispatch`, which broke the site in the way that I was betting on), but I'm not sure where that leaves me for what is going wrong right now.  Unless the documentation I've seen is incorrect and **SMTPPro** doesn't have the event defined or firing.

So here is what I've done.

in *$INST_HOME/app/code/local/Myorganization* I've created the tree:

> drwxrwsr-x 3 dgetsman   src 4096 Jul  1 03:38 Core.bak drwxrwsr-x 2
>   scriptuser src 4096 Jul  2 20:57 etc  drwxrwsr-x 2 scriptuser src 4096
>   Jul  1 01:24 Helper drwxrwsr-x 2 dgetsman   src 4096 Jul  2 20:42
>   Model
>
> Emailblacklist/Core.bak:  total 4  drwxrwsr-x 2 dgetsman src 4096 Jul 
>   2 20:30 Model
>
> Emailblacklist/Core.bak/Model:  total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 dgetsman src 921 Jul  1 03:41 Email.php
>
> Emailblacklist/etc: total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 scriptuser src 998 Jul  2 20:57 config.xml
>
> Emailblacklist/Helper: total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 scriptuser src 86 Jul  1 01:24 Data.php
>
> Emailblacklist/Model: total 4
>   -rw-rw-r-- 1 dgetsman src 201 Jul  2 02:05 Observer.php

Please note that *Core.bak* only includes some vestigial code that I was working on from when I was still attempting to go about this via overriding the `getTemplateSubject()` method.

Contents of *Emailblacklist/etc/config.xml* follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config>
    <modules>
        <Myorganization_Emailblacklist>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myorganization_Emailblacklist>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <helpers>
        <emailblacklist>
            <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Helper</class>
        </emailblacklist>
      </helpers>
      <models>
        <myorganization_emailblacklist>
          <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Model</class>
        </myorganization_emailblacklist>
      </models>
      <events>
        <!-- for debugging purposes
             <controller_action_predispatch> -->
        <aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
          <observers>
            <myorganization_emailblacklist>
              <class>myorganization_emailblacklist/observer</class>
              <method>watchEmails</method>
            </myorganization_emailblacklist>
          </observers>
        </aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
        <!-- debugging: </controller_action_predispatch> -->
      </events>
    </global>
  </config>
```

Contents of *Emailblacklist/Helper/Data.php* follow:

```
<?php
class Uselite_Emailblacklist_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

Contents of *Emailblacklist/Model/Observer.php* follow:

```
<?php
class Uselite_Emailblacklist_Model_Observer {
    public function watchEmails(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent();

        die(var_dump($order));

    }
}
```

As can be assumed from the aforementioned code, I'm hoping at this point just to get a dump of `$order` at this point.  Absolutely anything helpful will be very much appreciated.  Thanks for your time and consideration.  Please also feel free to let me know if I've forgotten to include any information that will be helpful to the troubleshooting process here.

Answer (score 0):

IN `config.xml` could you try

```
<events>
   <aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
       <observers>
          <myorganization_emailblacklist_model_observer>
               <type>singleton</type>
               <class>Myorganization_Emailblacklist_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>watchEmails</method>
           </myorganization_emailblacklist_model_observer>
        </observers>
    </aschroder_smtppro_before_send>
</events>
```

Comment: I've tried that configuration, and it doesn't seem to be changing any of the functionality (or lack thereof) that I'm dealing with right now.  Is the _myorganization_emailblacklist_ or _myorganization_emailblacklist_model_observer_ tag something that's completely arbitrary, do you know?  *flailing*

Comment: `<myorganization_blacklist_model_observer>` refers to the path to the `Observer.php` file

Comment: Sorry, mistyped the tag there. Actually, I 've just noticed that you have an extra directory in the path to `Observer.php`. I didn't realise it was there before. So that tag should probably be `<myorganization_emailblacklist_core.bak_model_observer>`. Either that or change the directory structure to not include the `Core.bak` directory.

Comment: Welll, the observer was in the _Model_ directory, which held _Observer.php_.  _Core.bak_ only held _Data.php_, which was a vestigial remnant from when I was trying to overload a class to handle this.  Anyway, I deleted it from the hierarchy, despite the fact that it wasn't referenced in any tags.

Comment: I managed to tie into a different event now that seems applicable, just a little more esoteric.  **aschroder_smtppro_template_before_send** instead of the previous _aschroder_smtppro_before_send_.  At least now I know it's doing something with the code.  When _success.phtml_ is close to the end of its run, it's breaking and leaving me at the chromium 'Aw, Snap' page loading error page.  I can't find anything in the logs telling me what/where might be going wrong now.  Any suggestions, @Alistair67?

Comment: Don't know why that would happen. Does it occur whether or not your code blocks an email being sent?

Comment: I've actually managed to nail down, strangely enough, the fact that the code is only crashing if I'm utilizing `Mage::log()`, `var_dump()`, or `var_export()`.  Having a bit of a conundrum on figuring out what to use to learn more about _$observer_ and _$order_, specifically, so that I can see if I can implement what I need to easily now.